# Ошибка при установке react-ace

Tags: reactjs

нужно установить react-ace.
При установке выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В сообщении говорится что react версии 18 не поддерживается, попробуйте понизить версию react и установить снова.
В файле `package.json` меняете эти строки на:

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
```

Потом выполняете `npm install`

Потом выполняете `npm install react-ace`